# Deformed object size in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg

[image]

I have a lot of icons, there are 100 artboard, and I always type the object size with exact number 95px × 95px.

The problem is, every I leave the object and back again select the object, that object always deformed the size. At my screenshot above, the object width changed to 94.996px

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I can't reproduce this problem.  But it looks like it could be a tiny rounding error or perhaps the image was not square to begin with. Hard to tell.

Comment: For a drawing like this you should constrain proportions so it doesn't get deformed. Are you doing that? Then it could simply be that the drawing doesn't fit into a square to begin with.

Comment: Hard to say. My initial guess is you have pixel snapping on but your arboard does not snap to your pixel grid. But then i wouldnt know because the only reason to enable pixel snapping is to get hard to resolve problems down the line i guess. So why one would choose to do so is beyond me.

Comment: hi @joojaa , absolutely i am did not snap to anything

Comment: Cant replicate the problem except with pixel snapping on. Maybe you have the big canvas mode enabled? Any chance of a file with which minimally demonstrates the problem.